# Prove that if $A$ is algebra generated by $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ then $A = \{ f\in C_b(\mathbb R ) : f(t) = f(t + 2\pi )$ for all $t \in \mathbb R\}$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding a closed subalgebra generated by functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103675/finding-a-closed-subalgebra-generated-by-functions)

Let $A$ be the uniformly closed subalgebra of $C_b(\mathbb{R} )$ generated by $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Prove: $A = \{ f\in C_b(\mathbb{R} ) : f(t) = f(t + 2\pi )$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R} \} $.

Comment: That helps, thank you

Comment: yes, i got it, thank you